# How can a wandering, destitute GURPS DFRPG Cleric cast high cost spells?

Tags: magic, gurps-dungeon-fantasy

In GURPS *Dungeon Fantasy/DFRPG*, there's at least one spell offered to Clerics (even with low Power Investiture, meaning it's available to Henchman level or Priest lens characters) that has a relatively high casting cost: Final Rest at 20 FP.

A low point total character (say, a 187 point Ally, never mind a 125 point Henchman Initiate), or a character who has multiclassed by taking a Priest lens on top of another level class) would be unable to cast this spell without drawing a number of hit points to power the spell (in my case, with a shaved down Cleric template, I'd have to use 7 HP).  The skill penalty of -1 per HP used to power a spell means this reduced-point character would be casting at effective skill 6 -- not a recipe for success.

A large enough Power Item to avoid drawing HP would, at the least, require either spending on a Wealth level or spending a one-time point for starting cash, and would still be one use between returns to base to have an NPC recharge the Item.  Casting as Ceremonial Magic, requires Skill 15 and either one or more partners with the same or higher skill (requiring duplication between two healers, in my case), or a congregation large enough to do the job by contributing 1-3 FP each, depending on their abilities -- and that's a bit of a problem to travel potentially weeks from home base with.

My GM has suggested using *paut* (a potion found in DF:1), but as I read it, that only replaces spent fatigue, rather than letting the user store up FP prior to a casting.

What's the most effective method for a sub-250 point Cleric with neither traveling congregation or same-spell, same caster type partner to cast costly spells like Final Rest?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the intent of the authors, something only they can really answer.

Comment: @Mołot That's why I asked if there was any statement from the game designers.  The SJGames team is usually fairly open, but I don't read a bunch of game publications -- there just aren't enough hours.

Comment: Related: [How would learning Share Energy unbalance GURPS Dungeon Fantasy/DFRPG?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164966/how-would-learning-share-energy-unbalance-gurps-dungeon-fantasy-dfrpg)

Comment: Can you clarify why you think characters of the power level you describe _should_ be able to reliably cast _final rest_? The overall mechanical effect of a high FP cost is to make the spell only castable by higher-point characters, so certainly the implied designer intent can be read as being that a sub-250 point Cleric can't use that spell.

Comment: @Marq That spell has a low PI requirement and for a cleric, there are no prerequisites, so it's *available* to 125 point cleric Initiates.  Making a spell available that can't actually be cast seems like designing a trap into the rules.

Comment: I don't know about Dungeon Fantasy, but in 4e _Magic_, Final Rest has the additional condition that it can _only_ be cast ceremonially. My reading (again, of the general magic rules, not DF specifically) is that it has no prerequisites so that it's available to "village priest" NPCs who use it as part of funeral rites, and may know no other spells (and thus can learn it at 15+), and can cast it with the help of a dozen lay worshippers assisting.

Comment: @marq you might be right -- but since asking about even *statements of* designer intent gets questions closed, we'll never know.

Comment: Marq - that's the answer.  It's a ceremonial magic spell, and as such, it cannot be cast without assistants R.A.W.; the premise of the question makes the answer "You can't."  Please submit that as an answer.